# define keyboard shortcuts for chrome developer tools commands

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-devtools

I need a faster way to invoke the copy command, currently I am using the context menu in the chrome developer tools as shown in this picture:

[image]

But, I was wondering if there is a faster way of achieving the same result. Or is it possible to define keyboard shortcuts for chrome developer tools commands?

PS: I need to "copy link address" as highlighted in the picture in the Network tab of chrome developer tools for media files.

Answer (score -1):

The solution to your problem is [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/)

With it you can write a script that does all the hard work for you. Mapping the actions required to 'right-click > copy link address' to a single key on the keyboard.

To right-click with the keyboard you must press Shift+F10. This keyboard shortcut does not interfere with any default chrome shortcuts so you're safe to use it within your script.

The following script will copy link address automatically when you click your media file and press F1 on your keyboard (you're free to change it to any key you like)

Step 1 - Download and install [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/)

Step 2 - Right click on your desktop > New AutoHotKey script

Step 3 - Open the AHK file in Notepad and paste in the following script:

```
F1::

{
Send, +{F10}
Sleep, 50
Send, {Down}
Sleep, 50
Send, {Down}
Sleep, 50
Send, {Down}
Sleep, 50
Send, {Down}
Sleep, 50
Send, {Right}
Sleep, 50
Send, {Enter}
}
```

If you select your media file and hit F1 it will perform the actions you usually do using the mouse but without you physically having to do it yourself.

The 'Sleep' command value is set to 50ms. You can change this value if the script is running too fast to what you want but it should be fine.

Step 4 - Double click your script to activate it. Right click the green 'H' icon in your hidden icons (start bar) to exit the script whenever you like.

Comment: I am already using autohotkey and also have created an autohotkey script to do the same thing, but the problem is when your system is heavily loaded with programs, it does not give the desired results.

Comment: I am looking for a more straight forward way.

Comment: understandable.... seems like you might need to email google asking for this to be implemented. Seems odd they haven't considered the need for devs to do this in an easier way. good luck with it!